# how to geowebcache my own group layer in geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I am unable to geowebcache my layer group in geoserver. But in Geowebcache demo page, default layer groups are available. How to add my group layer into geowebcache?
please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/setup.html

GeoWebCache does not work when multiple GeoServer instances are configured to use the same data directory. The H2 database crashes during initialization when the second instance is started.

Two possible workarounds:

- Delete gwc*.jar in WEB-INF/lib and restart GeoServer. This disables GeoWebCache. If you wish, you can run a separate instance in front of all your GeoServer instances.
- **Set the variable GEOWEBCACHE_CACHE_DIR, described above, to point to a local directory for each instance.**